# While printing report content divide on two pages

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

When I print the report it cut the content on two page. I want if the content increases then **with regards** come in next page.

```
<tr>
  <td style="padding-bottom:10px;">Terms &amp; Conditions</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="padding-left:20px;">
    <span t-if="doc.comment">
      <t t-set="comment" t-value="doc.comment.split('\n')"/>
        <ol>
          <t t-foreach="comment" t-as="pt">
            <li><span t-esc="pt"/></li>
          </t>
        </ol>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="padding-top:10px;page-break-inside:avoid;">With regards</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="padding-top: 120px;page-break-inside:avoid;">.........................................</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Mandy Tsang</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Director</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here, I attach the file what currently print.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLRwG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLRwG.png)
I want **with regards** come in next page

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you wanna add a page break before `With regards` you should split your table before that part into 2 tables and add and `style="page-break-before:always;"` to instruct report engine to make a page break before the desired content.